# VIM change folding markdown to show lines and number of words using vimrc

Tags: vim, markdown, folding

I'm using GVIM on windows for writing sf novels and I fold the chapters so I can hide them away. When folded the chapter 'lines' show something like this:

```
##1 – Spaceman Spoof Encounters the Watterson........ 115 lines [2.4%] +--+--
```

This is useful but only a little bit. Some lines may be just a few words and others might be well over a 100 words. What I'd prefer is a line count and a word count like this:

```
##1 – Spaceman Spoof Encounters the Watterson........ l:115 w:1032 [4.4%] +--+--
```

with the percentage being that for the words and not for the lines. Any help would sure be appreciated.

Here's the folding section of my `_vimrc`:

```
function! MarkdownFolds()
    let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
    if match(thisline, '^##') >= 0
        return ">2"
    elseif match(thisline, '^#') >= 0
        return ">1"
    else
        return "="
    endif
endfunction

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=MarkdownFolds()

function! MarkdownFoldText()
    "get first non-blank line
    let fs = v:foldstart
    while getline(fs) =~ '^\s*$' | let fs = nextnonblank(fs + 1)
    endwhile
    if fs > v:foldend
        let line = getline(v:foldstart)
    else
        let line = substitute(getline(fs), '\t', repeat(' ', &tabstop), 'g')
    endif

    let w = winwidth(0) - &foldcolumn - (&number ? 8 : 0)
    let foldSize = 1 + v:foldend - v:foldstart
    let foldWords = v:foldend,v:foldstart!wc -w
    let foldSizeStr = " " . foldSize . " lines "
    let foldWordsStr = " " . foldWords . " w "
    let foldLevelStr = repeat("+--", v:foldlevel)
    let lineCount = line("$")
    let foldPercentage = printf("[%.1f", (foldSize*1.0)/lineCount*100) . "%] "
    " let expansionString = "."
    let expansionString = repeat(".", w - strwidth(foldSizeStr.line.foldLevelStr.foldPercentage))
    return line . expansionString . foldSizeStr . foldPercentage . foldLevelStr
    " return line . expansionString . foldSizeStr . foldPercentage . foldWordsStr . foldLevelStr
    " return line . "......" . foldSizeStr . foldPercentage . foldLevelStr
endfunction

setlocal foldtext=MarkdownFoldText()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
function! MarkdownFoldText()
    "get first non-blank line
    let fs = v:foldstart
    while getline(fs) =~ '^\s*$' | let fs = nextnonblank(fs + 1)
    endwhile
    if fs > v:foldend
        let line = getline(v:foldstart)
    else
        let line = substitute(getline(fs), '\t', repeat(' ', &tabstop), 'g')
    endif

    let w = winwidth(0) - &foldcolumn - (&number ? 8 : 0)
    let foldSize = 1 + v:foldend - v:foldstart

    let i = 0
    let foldWords=0
    let wordCount=0
    while (i<line('$'))
      let lineWords = len(split(getline(i)))
      if (i<=v:foldend && i>= v:foldstart)
        let foldWords = foldWords + lineWords
      endif
      let wordCount += lineWords
      let i += 1
    endwhile

    let foldWordsStr = " " . foldWords . " w,"
    let foldSizeStr = foldWordsStr . foldSize . " lines "
    let foldLevelStr = repeat("+--", v:foldlevel)
    let foldPercentage = printf("[%.1f", (foldWords*1.0)/wordCount*100) . "%] "
    let expansionString = repeat(".", w - strwidth(foldSizeStr.line.foldLevelStr.foldPercentage))
    return line . expansionString . foldSizeStr . foldPercentage . foldLevelStr
endfunction
```

The idea is to count the global word count, and the one that is just in the selected region at the same time.

Then we replace the percentage with the word count as requested.

Comment: That works beautifully simonpierre. I tried to vote it up but I'm afraid I don't have enough points to do that.

Comment: There is a downside to this as the word count in a novel (especially one over 100K words) requires quite a bit of calculation so there's a significant delay when opening folds but this is worth it when I'm trying to figure out if certain chapters are too word heavy. I may want to simply use two different _vimrc files and swap them out.

Comment: I can work on this and optimize this: looks like the word count is recalculated several times. I will see if I can manage this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using wordcount() function, this time:

```
function! MarkdownFoldText()
    "get first non-blank line
    let fs = v:foldstart
    while getline(fs) =~ '^\s*$' | let fs = nextnonblank(fs + 1)
    endwhile
    if fs > v:foldend
        let line = getline(v:foldstart)
    else
        let line = substitute(getline(fs), '\t', repeat(' ', &tabstop), 'g')
    endif

    let w = winwidth(0) - &foldcolumn - (&number ? 8 : 0)
    let foldSize = 1 + v:foldend - v:foldstart

    let i = v:foldstart
    let foldWords=0
    while (i<v:foldend)
      let lineWords = len(split(getline(i)))
      let foldWords = foldWords + lineWords
      let i += 1
    endwhile
    let wordCount = wordcount()["words"]

    " let foldWords = v:foldend,v:foldstart!wc -w
    let foldWordsStr = " " . foldWords . " w,"
    let foldSizeStr = foldWordsStr . foldSize . " lines "
    let foldLevelStr = repeat("+--", v:foldlevel)
    let foldPercentage = printf("[%.1f", (foldWords*1.0)/wordCount*100) . "%] "
    " let expansionString = "."
    let expansionString = repeat(".", w - strwidth(foldSizeStr.line.foldLevelStr.foldPercentage))
    return line . expansionString . foldSizeStr . foldPercentage . foldLevelStr
    " return line . expansionString . foldSizeStr . foldPercentage . foldWordsStr . foldLevelStr
    " return line . "......" . foldSizeStr . foldPercentage . foldLevelStr
endfunction
```

It should be faster. Not that the percentage is how much this folder represents compared to the whole buffer. With the wordcount() function, how far are we from the end would be trivial to build.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work simonpierre. The folded lines are just a 0 with that.

Comment: Not on my machine:

```
# Upgrading Nexus core switches............. 404 w,95 lines [19.3%] +--
# conf t..................................... 169 w,40 lines [8.1%] +--
# conf t...................................... 44 w,10 lines [2.1%] +--
```